# How to create Docker-image from my app? It's node.js application that use MongoDB

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have node-applicatiot. It's running from terminal and do some operations. Operations include work with database "MongoDB".
I need to write dockerfile that create Docker-image from my app.
I read many information, but examples that I found tell about how to create web-app that running on some port. I need just run app from terminal.
What steps I must do?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately your question is rather vague and I am not really familiar with nodeJs, but as far as my understanding of Docker goes I will try and point you in some direction where you might find the information you are looking for or at least help you to ask a more specific question.

From what I can tell what you are looking for is probably a docker image that contains a nodeJs-Server. Then you would download that image and create a container from it, you would map the folder containing your node-application as a volume into the container, so the node-Server inside the container can deploy your application.

At our company we use a JBoss-Application Server inside a Docker-Container to deploy our Java-Applications in pretty much the way I described. Maybe you should look for some of the words I used on Google (docker volume, docker container, etc.), there are actually lots of documentation and tutorials on docker out there. 
A good way to start would probably be here https://docs.docker.com/ ;)